# bigquery subtract 3 business days from date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am aware that you can subtract days from a date as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE "2008-12-25", INTERVAL 3 DAY) as three_days_ago;
```

but how do I subtract 3 `business` days?

Comment: Where is the sample data?

Comment: Are you using standard or legacy SQL?

Comment: standard SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a `CASE` expression

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) IN (2, 3, 4)    -- Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
         THEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
         WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1
         THEN DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
         ELSE DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 3 DAY) END AS three_days_ago
FROM yourTable;
```

For Sunday, we need to add one day to get past Saturday, which can't be counted.  Similarly, for Monday through Wednesday, we need to add two days to cover the entire weekend, which can't be counted.  For Thursday through Saturday, we can just subtract 3 days, all of which will be business days.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it replies my question, but I oversimplified my problem. My real issue is in this other question, which I hope you can help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801623/google-bigquery-subtract-any-number-of-business-day-from-date

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Bro it will work in all cases.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME, @DAYS_EXTEND INT, @HOLIDAYS VARCHAR(100) , @COUNTER INT

--ARGUMENTS
SET @DATE = '2018-04-12'
SET @DAYS_EXTEND  = 3
SET @HOLIDAYS  = 'SAT,SUN'   --REQUIRED OFF DAYS LIST COMM SEPERATED
------------------------------------

    SET @COUNTER = @DAYS_EXTEND  
    WHILE @COUNTER > 0 
    BEGIN

        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER -1
        SET @DATE  = @DATE +1

        IF  @HOLIDAYS  LIKE '%'+LOWER(LEFT(DATENAME(DW,@DATE) ,3))+'%'  
        BEGIN
            SET @DAYS_EXTEND = @DAYS_EXTEND +1
            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER +1;
        END
    END
    SELECT @DATE AS 'DATE_AFTER_EXTENDED_BUSINESS_DAYS'
```