# How to add SQL to check if there's outage in the recent weekdays only?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I run an audit of businesses to see if they are missing revenue or clients and produce a dataset that is comprised of any weekday date that the business failed any revenue/client metric (=$0/0) to produce the following dataset:

```
Date      |Business|Revenue1|Revenue2|Num_Clients1|Num_Clients2
4-18-2022 |1111    |$0      |$0      |0           |0    
4-15-2022 |1111    |$0      |$0      |0           |0    
4-18-2022 |2222    |$0      |$0      |0           |0    
4-14-2022 |2222    |$0      |$0      |0           |0         
4-15-2022 |3333    |$0      |$0      |0           |0             
4-13-2022 |3333    |$0      |$0      |0           |0
```

Today = 4-19-2022

If the practice has a non-zero metric value on a given weekday then it won't have a row in the aforementioned dataset.

I'd like to get a list of businesses that have all zero metrics in the last consecutive two weekdays before today (the day before yesterday and yesterday).

In this case that would be Business 1111. Business 2222 does not qualify because 4-15-2022 did not fail the audit. Business 3333 does not qualify because 4-15-2022 and 4-13-2022 are not the latest two consecutive weekdays relative to today.

How can I accomplish this in SQL? I am thinking about checking if a running total = 2 but I don't know how to do that just relative to the last two weekdays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample data you have provided. Consider the query below where it calculate for the prev day and prev 2 days of the current date. Filter the data where it has either prev day and prev 2 days and count per `Business`. If a record got a `count = 2` then it has data for the prev 2 days.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION working_days_diff(the_date DATE, num_of_days INT64) AS
  (
    DATE_SUB(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM the_date) IN (2,3,4,5,6,7)
      THEN
        CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM the_date) - MOD(num_of_days, 5)) > 1
        THEN DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL MOD(num_of_days, 5) DAY)
        ELSE DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL (MOD(num_of_days, 5) + 2) DAY)
        END
      ELSE
        DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL (MOD(num_of_days, 5) +1) DAY)
    END, INTERVAL DIV(num_of_days, 5) WEEK) 
); -- I got this function here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801623/google-bigquery-subtract-any-number-of-business-day-from-date

with data as (
select date('2022-04-18') as Date, 1111 as Business, 0 as Revenue1, 0 as Revenue2, 0 as Num_Clients1, 0 as Num_Clients2,
union all select date('2022-04-15') as Date, 1111 as Business, 0 as Revenue1, 0 as Revenue2, 0 as Num_Clients1, 0 as Num_Clients2,
union all select date('2022-04-18') as Date, 2222 as Business, 0 as Revenue1, 0 as Revenue2, 0 as Num_Clients1, 0 as Num_Clients2,
union all select date('2022-04-14') as Date, 2222 as Business, 0 as Revenue1, 0 as Revenue2, 0 as Num_Clients1, 0 as Num_Clients2,
union all select date('2022-04-15') as Date, 3333 as Business, 0 as Revenue1, 0 as Revenue2, 0 as Num_Clients1, 0 as Num_Clients2,
union all select date('2022-04-13') as Date, 3333 as Business, 0 as Revenue1, 0 as Revenue2, 0 as Num_Clients1, 0 as Num_Clients2,
),

add_prev_days as (
select *, 
    date('2022-04-19') as today, -- replace with current_date()
    working_days_diff(DATE('2022-04-19'), 1)  as prev_day, -- replace with current_date()
    working_days_diff(DATE('2022-04-19'), 2)  as prev_2_day, -- replace with current_date()
from data
),

add_count as (
select *, 
    count(Business) over (partition by Business) as count_bus
from add_prev_days 
    where (prev_day = Date or prev_2_day = Date) 
)

select Date,
    Business,
    Revenue1,
    Revenue2,
    Num_Clients1, 
    Num_Clients2 
from add_count
    where count_bus = 2
```

Sample output:

[image]

NOTE: I hard coded '2022-04-19' to act as the current date so the query would work. Replace this value with `current_date()` to fit your use case.